# How do you make duplicate rows from same column into two separate column?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

After importing CSV in pandas. i noticed one of the column "subject" has two different categories. in the csv file for subject column it has 'Tot' and 'voluntary' in one column but different rows.

How would make tot and voluntary into two separate column ? so that the rows doesn't duplicated

Below is the image of the csv on pandas

[image]

Comment: From you data, the rows don't seem to be duplicating? Can you provide a smaller sample clearly showing rows you believe are being duplicated.

Comment: You might be looking for [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html), e.g., `pd.pivot_table(health_clean_df, values='hSpend_val', index=['LocationTime','LOCATION','TIME'], columns=['SUBJECT'])`

Comment: @GalodoLeste its not duplicating. so whats happening is in the csv file its showing TOT and voluntary in on column. i wanted to split tot and voluntary into two columns.

Comment: @harryhaller in the subject column it has TOT and voluntary. i wanted that to be in separate column.

Comment: Are you asking to change the SUBJECT column, that includes values of TOT and VOLUNTARY, into two columns, TOT and VOLUNTARY, each having True or False values?